# the problem [object object] is displayed in html page when i run my ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I want to read a list ('news') from my firebase in my ionic 3 app 
and when I run this app its shown in a page [object object] only.

Can someone tell me the solution ?

My code is below here :

[home.ts]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList  } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  newsList: AngularFireList<any[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.newsList = this.database.list('news');



  }

}
```

[home.html]

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item >
      <h2>{{newsList}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

The result is showed just [object object]

Comment: check with console.log(this.newsList) and paste here what u see

Comment: i checked now and this i see now 

{query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an object as a h2. You can try useing ngFor.

```
   <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of newList">
      <h2>{{item}}</h2> //or item.subitem, depends of your object or what you want to show.
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: this error i see it now
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: This is cuz you are working with an object when what you need is an array. Try to iterate your object creating an array with their elements.
for (var i in object){ newArrar.push(object[i])}
It will be easier if you can bring an example about how is the structure of your "newList"

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
 this.newsList = JSON.stringify(this.database.list('news'));
```

html

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of newList">
      <h2>{{item}}</h2> //or item.subitem, depends of your object or what you want to show.
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```